How can I get my window screen to stay in place?
We had this window installed a few months back and the screen never stays in. There are set screws but they just apply pressure to the frame and there are no holes they go into. What am I doing wrong?



IME the screen fasteners are typically placed on the inside-the-house side of the window.  Are you sure they're the right orientation?

By definition, egress systems must allow for rapid and unimpeded exit from a building.
Make a mark at the centerline where the buttons are on the screen. Insert the screen into the opening. Transfer the marks from the screen to the frame.
From the inside face of the screen, measure the distance from the edge of the frame to the center of the button. Transfer that dimension to the frame starting from the screen stop on the frame.
Using a drill the same diameter as the button, drill enough of a surface impression on the mark to properly seat the button.
Or get the company that installed the window to do it as a warranty repair.

Even surface dimples will probably result in any warranty claim being declined.

This is a concern for your installer to address. If you don't want to do that, here are some ideas.
The retention buttons appear to be threaded. Try running them in a bit further to create slightly more tension.
If that doesn't work, try some double-sided foam or silicone tape under the buttons.
I would not put any holes in the window. You'll void your warranty, create leaks, and potentially create a safety concern. Small kids and anyone with physical weakness may not be able to overcome the barrier in a fire.

The screen can’t install from the inside because it won’t fit. I am waiting for the installer to get back to me but the communication is very bad. I thought about just putting a small silicone bead to help keep it in place. The screen itself is only held in place with the rubber spline which is on the outside. Even if the metal screen frame was secured anyone could push on the actual screen to have it pop out from the frame I would think.

This is a European style (tilt and) turn window. Screens for these types of windows are not big in Europe and their designs tend towards a kludge because the demand is so low. Try Isherwood's idea of foam tape to increase tension on the buttons.
